# jQuery document.on() child selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a ul and i want create an alert when i click on a child li.

```
<ul id="myul">
    <div class="test">
        <div class="test1">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </div>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Something like that is possible:

```
$(document).on('click', '#myul.find(li)', function()
{
   alert('hey!');
}
```

I can't use `#myul > li` because I have other child before `li`.

Comment: It's not semantically correct to use a `div` in between `ul` and `li` elements :) You can use `$('#myul').on('click','li', urFunction)` - that will invoke your function for click event on any `li` inside your `ul`

Comment: as @Arkantos has rightfully said this isn't structurally sound code. li tags should always be directly under ul tags. Could you not put your div tags outside of your ul? Then your example code would work.

Comment: @Arkantos Hello and thanks, unfortunately I use a widget for adding a custom scrollbar for this ul and this widget creates two div.

Comment: Ok.. but if you have control over that widget source or if you know someone who can edit that, tell them to follow the semantics. Anyways I posted an answer with your current markup, have a look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$(document).on('click','#myul li', eventHandler)
```

which means you're registering an event handler on the document but `eventHandler` will be invoked only when the event originated from `#myul li` i.e for any `li` child of `myul`, not just the immediate child, can be a descendant as well which fits your case.

But I suggest that you even reduce the scope of the event registration to the closest ancestor of `li` like below.

```
$('#myul').on('click','li', eventHandler)
```

Answer (score 1):

`ul` elements can only contain `li` elements eventually mixed with `ol` and `ul` elements. You can can fix your html and jquery to be like:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#myul ul li', function() {
  alert('hey!');
});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myul">
  <li class="test">
    <ul class="test1">
      <li>rasd</li>
      <li>sadsad</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply css child selector as below mentioned. It will apply direct children not just any descendant.

Note: As per http://w3.org standards you can't make the div direct children of ul. The div tag should come inside the li's.

```
jQuery("#myul > li").click(function(){

    alert('hey!');

});
```

Comment: `#myul > li` means only direct children not just any descendant :) You should update your answer

Comment: @Arkantos: - Yes, I did, Thanks very much!!

Comment: Your answer still doesn't solve OP's issue considering his mark-up where `li` is not a direct child of `ul`.. Please review and update :)

Comment: @Arkantos:- As per w3.org standards. We can't place the div as a direct  child of ul. The div tag should come inside the li's :)

Comment: Yup. I pointed this one to OP but he's using some widget on which he has no control, so just trying to solve the issue in it's current state